# Error Vue Countdown

Tags: vue.js

Estoy tratando de implementar un contador y quiero hacer que cuando este llegue a 0 se ejecute X acción, de prueba con un console.log bastaría, pero no logro poder hacerlo andar ya que mi comprensión de la propiedad Watch no es mucha.

Actualmente en la parte visual, si llego a 0 me salta el mensaje ese que tengo en el v-else "llegaste a 0" pero yo quiero hacer en la parte del script, porque cuando llegue a 0 tendría que ejecutar un metodo, como se les ocurre que podría hacer?

Sin más preámbulos les dejo el código.

HTML

```
    <div id="vue">
    <div v-if="timerCount > 0">
    {{ timerCount }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
    llegaste a 0
    </div>
    </div>
```

VUE

```
<script>
var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#vue", 
    data:{
        timerCount: 30
    },
    watch: {

         timerCount: {
                  handler(value) {

                      if (value > 0) {
                      setTimeout(() => {
                          this.timerCount--;
                        }, 1000);
                      }            

                  },
           immediate: true 
          }

}
});
</script>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda,
Saludos cordiaales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo podrías hacer más fácil con `setInterval` en el `mounted` o como una función definida en los `methods` simplementa guardas el identificador del intervalo u cuando se cumpla la condición de parada limpias el intervalo usando `clearInterval`

Tu código quedaría así:

```js
var vue = new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data: {
    timerCount: 5
  },
  mounted() {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.timerCount--;
            
      if (this.timerCount === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        // Ejecuta alguna funcion e.g: 
        console.log('Hello world');
      }
    }, 1000);
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="vue">
    <div v-if="timerCount > 0">
        {{ timerCount }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        llegaste a 0
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mil gracias @Daniel Rodriguez Meza, me funciono perfectamente y además me ayudo a solucionar el tema del delay, que no se porque con el setTimeout yo cuando traia de nuevo el timerCount de una api, y quería volverlo a traer en una siguiente pantalla me andaba mucho más rapido que la primera vez(siempre era el mismo campo que se pisaba). Y esto me ayudo a hacerlo funcionar correctamente, a que se puede deber? Tenes idea? Desde ya muchas gracias, pregunta solucionada